# Calculated Fields in excel pivot

Tags: excel

I have column ('CSAT') in a sheet that has numbers 1 and 0 in each cell. '1' represents 'Satisfied' and '0' represents 'Disatisfied'. I want to make a pivot from this sheet and have a new calculated field in it ('CSAT %') that will give me the score by dividing (Total 'Satisfied') count by (Total 'Dissatisfied + Total 'Satisfied') * 100.

I tried with COUNTIF but i dont think we can use this formula in pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculated Fields and Items in PivotTables are tricky. The main tripping point is understanding that Calculated Fields and Items operate on the totals, not on the individual values in the underlying data.

For example, if you created a new Field that was equal to `Field1 * Field2` and data is being summarized by SUM, Excel doesn't multiply all of the respective values in each field and then sum the results. It first sums the fields for each category and then multiplies those results. What it's really doing is `SUM(Field1) * SUM(Field2)` for each category.

You can use some worksheet functions in the calculated fields, but you have to remember you're still operating on the totals. So if you created a new Field that was equal to `Count(Field1) * Count(Field2)`, you're (almost) always just going to get an answer of 1. This is because the calculation is actually doing `Count(SUM(Field1)) * Count(SUM(Field2))` for each category. The sum of each field is a single number, so the calculation is just doing `1*1` for each category.

So for this reason, you can't use aggregating functions like SUMIF or COUNTIF which need to look at each individual elements. Since you need to look at individual elements, you actually can't use a Calculated Field for your solution at all.

What you *can* do is use a Calculated Item!

The main catch here is you can't use any field in more than 1 location when calculated items are involved. Excel just throws an error message saying you're not allowed.

So if you have a category column as well as the CSAT column, you need to create another dummy column full of 1's to operate on.

You can then set up pivot table as follows:

1. Category field to Rows.
2. Dummy field to Data area, summarized by Sum
3. CSAT field to Columns
4. Click on the CSAT column headers in the pivot table and choose: PivotTable Tools > Fields, Items, & Sets > Calculated Item
5. Set Name for your new Item to CSAT%
6. Enter the formula: ='1'/('0'+'1')
7. On the CSAT field, hide items 1 and 0, so only the CSAT% field is visible

[image: Settings]

Result:

[image: Result]

A couple of notes:

- When entering fields and items in calculated fields and items, do so by placing the cursor where you want in the Formula then double clicking on the field/item name from the lists below. This will add brackets and quotes as required in the correct format.
- Note that the formula doesn't need SUM around the item names, because calculated fields/items always work on the total of values. They are totalled according to how the data is summarized in the pivot table.
- The dummy column was added with all values of 1 so that summing these values gives you the count, from which the percentage can be calculated using the formula specified.

Answer (score 0):

Answer without using calculated fields:

Assuming you have categories in the row fields, you can put CSAT as a column field as well as a data field then choose to summarize values by Count and show values as a percentage of row totals:

After putting CSAT in column and data fields, right click on the data and select Summarize Values By > More Options...

First choose to Summarize Values By Count:

[image]

Then click Show Values As tab and select % of Row Total:

[image]

You'll then have percentage of 1's under the CSAT=1 column:

[image]